# Angularjs not attaching dynamically created qrcode on FIRST call of repeating function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a situation where at the end of ng-repeat I am executing a function that will then attach qrcodes into `<DIV>`s that were just created in the ng-repeat.  At the end of that function is a call to repeat the same function every 5 minutes to refresh the QRCodes.

In general it works, except for the FIRST execution of the function, its called correctly and executes correctly except that the qrcode is not being added to the DIVs.  But on the 2nd and all subsequent refresh calls it attaches the qrcode successfully.

HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="ticket in club.tickets" ng-init="$last && genQRCode()">
      <div id="ticketID_{{ticket.ticketID}}"></div>
      <div >{{ticket.ticketName}}</div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.ticketTimer ;
  $scope.genQRCode = function() {
    for (var x=0;x<$scope.club.tickets.length;x++) {
      var ticket = $scope.club.tickets[x] ;

      // remove any elements inside the DIV
      // needed for $timeout re-calling the genQRCode
      // as it will just attach another qrcode <canvas>, not overwriting the first
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#ticketID_'+ticket.ticketID)).empty() ;
  
      // this attaches a <canvas> to the DIV
      jQuery('#ticketID_'+ticket.ticketID).qrcode({width:150,height:150,text:"SomeString"}) ;
    }
    $scope.ticketTimer = $timeout(function(){
      console.log("Next QR triggered") ;
      $scope.genQRCode() ;
    },30000) ;  // 5 minutes = 300000    
  }
```

I suspect it has something to do with `jQuery` not recognizing that the #elementID(s) are created immediately after the ng-repeat, but can't figure my way around it yet.  But, the `angular.element(....).empty()` does not throw an error on the first call suggesting it does see the element DIV in the DOM.

On all refresh calls to `genQRCode`, the rendered DOM looks like this, the QR Code does appear in the `<canvas>` tag:

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in club.tickets" style="text-align:center;padding-left: 50px;padding-right:10px;" class="" ng-init="$last &amp;&amp; genQRCode()">
   <div id="ticketID_15">
     <canvas width="196" height="196"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div class="ng-binding">Entry</div>
</div>
```